# Declaring class as integer

Tags: c++, class, initialization, scope-resolution, scope-resolution-operator

```
class test {
public:
    static int n;
    test () { n++; };
    ~test () { n--; };
};

int test::n=0; //<----what is this step called? how can a class be declared as an integer?

int main () {
    test a;
    test b[5]; // I'm not sure what is going on here..is it an array?
    test * c = new test;
    cout << a.n << endl;
    delete c;
    cout << test::n << endl;
}
```

secondly, the output is 7,6 I'm not understanding how did it get 7, from where?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+static+member+initialization&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=Palemoon:en-US&client=palemoon

Answer (score 2):

From the statement-

```
int test::n=0;
```

'`::`' is called scope resolution operator. This operator is used here to initialize the static field n, not the class

Answer (score 1):

Static data members are declared in class. They are defined outside the class.

Thus in the class definition

```
class test {

public:
static int n;
test () { n++; };
~test () { n--; };
};
```

record

```
static int n;
```

only declares n. You need to define it that is to allocate memory for it.
And this

```
int test::n=0;
```

is its definition. `test::n` is a qualified name of the variable that denotes that n belongs to class test.

According to the class definition when an object of the class is constructed this static variable is increased

```
test () { n++; };
```

And when an object is destructed this static variable is decreased

```
~test () { n--; };
```

In fact this static variable plays a role of counting alive objects of the class.

Thus in main you defined object of the class with name a

```
test a;
```

Each time an object is defined the constructor of the class is called. Consequently n was increased and becomes equal to 1.
Adter defining array of 5 objects

```
test b[5];
```

n becomes equal to 6.

After dynamically allocating one more object

```
test * c = new test;
```

n becomes equal to 7.

After its explicit deleting

```
delete c;
```

n again becomes equal to 6 because called destructor decreased n.